# Cannot SSH to device using python script from Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am not sure if this is a python paramiko module problem or a ubuntu problem. But I thought I would try this place anyway.

I have SSH enabled in my other device and it works well!

But I just started learning python and wrote this simple python program to connect to the other device.

```
import paramiko
def open_ssh_conn(ip):
  try:
  #Logging into device

  session = paramiko.SSHClient()



  session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())



  session.connect(ip, username = "username", password = "password")



  connection = session.invoke_shell()

  except paramiko.AuthenticationException:

  print "* Invalid username or password!"

  print "* Closing program...\n"

  #Calling the SSH function
  open_ssh_conn("192.168.100.1")
```

But nothing happens when I run the program. Not even an error message. (I run it by typing

$ python2 testSsh1.py)

But when I try this command from the terminal **I can connect**. Any help is appreciated!

admin1ubu@ubuntu01:~$ ssh -l user1 192.168.100.1

Comment: If this is your script as-is, your last line that calls `open_ssh_conn` is indented which would make it part of the function. Try unindenting the last line (you'll probably get a different problem involving indentation of code after `try`).

Comment: in python you need to indent the line after `try`. Generally if there is a `:` indent the next line. Python parses code based on indentation, so whitespace is very important. Please Indent the try and except blocks, then unindent the last line.

Comment: Assuming indenting issues are taken care of, it is probably working as written. The SSH connection is being closed when the Python script exits/ends. You are probably assuming you would be left with an open login session.

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your help! birryree & matthew-ciaramitaro
Yes, turns out the problem was with indentation

@Deathgrip yes you are correct as well!
I as expecting to be left with an open login session. Thats exactly what I am trying to go for.
Do you have any suggestions to change the code to keep the session open?